# Windows 10 зависает при установке QT Creator

Tags: windows-10, qtcreator

Скачал онлайн загрузчик qt creator, выбрал последнюю версию и пару тулзов. Все скачалось, но при самой установке виндовс почти намертво виснет (устанавливал несколько раз с разными версиями, с тулзами и без, каждый раз установщик зависал в разных местах, прм этом винда отказывалась работать и вылетало сообщение: "Microsoft Windows не отвечает". Подскажите, в чем проблема?

Comment: отсекайте по мере сил - медленный диск (или уже умирает, либо места в притык), мало оперативки, антивирус (даже встроенный)

Comment: Диску два месяца, пустой полностью, винда на ссд отдельно. Оперативки 8 гб, попробую антивирус отключить.

Comment: то, что диску два месяца, ещё ничего не значит.

Comment: Поддерживаю. Тоже не могу установить Qt :-(
Стоит Windows 10 64 бита. При установке зависает винда.

Comment: У вас имя пользователя случайно не на русском? Из за этого могут быть проблемы с установкой.